# How to adjust sound properties, like with a graphic equalizer, in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I am running Ubuntu 9.10. How do I adjust the sound out to reduce or increase the bass and treble ranges of the sound?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [post on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1308838) on how you can use PulseAudio Equalizer.

Advantages:

> - Configurable 15 band equalizer for PulseAudio;
> - You can enable or disable equalized audio on-the-fly, without having to
>     restart any running applications;
> - Offers the choice of using equalized audio for the current session or
>     permanently;
> - No need to edit any configuration files by hand;
> - User-customizable: you can use any LADSPA audio processing plugin (which
>     can apply various audio effects beyond
>     equalization);
> - Packaged as a .deb file for easy installation;
> - Graphical User Interface.

Comment: I still need to try this out.